# Batch editing of users

Tags: batch-file, edit

Can anyone tell me how to batch edit users on a windows 7 computer. The computer i am after has around 80-90 users on it and i need to and one file to all of the users. If anyone knows a CMD command that would be grate or a script that would be even better

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a batch file for that ....

Just copy the file to the all users directory

That should do:...